# Synaptics touchpad LED support

Tags: linux, desktop, xorg, input, synaptic

How to enable support the LED in Synaptics touchpads?
I'm using Debian Jessie and xserver-xorg-input-synaptics ver. 1.8.1-1.

I found [patches by Takashi Iwai from SUSE](https://github.com/perusio/xorg-synaptics-led-support) for LED support in Synaptics touchpads and [Debian bug 609903](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=609903) "enable LEDDoubleTap feature".  But these patches are for Synaptics ver. < 1.8 and do not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/582809/comments/328):

> TODO for clickpad to work with the LED :
>
> (Enable the proposed archive for Ubuntu 12.04 :
>   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed After dist-upgrade, do
>   this :)
>
> 1. Build a xserver-xorg-input-synaptics with led support package :
>
>    ```
>    mkdir tmpbuild 
>    cd tmpbuild
>    apt-get source
>    xserver-xorg-input-synaptics d
>    cd xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-*/debian/patches 
>    wget https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/582809/+attachment/3183411/+files/200-add_led_support_with_double_tap-synaptics-1.6.0-mohegan_V1.patch
>    ls -1 2*.patch >> series
>    cd ../.. 
>    sudo apt-get build-dep xserver-xorg-input-synaptics 
>    debchange -i
>    ```
>
>    Add somme comments (for example, "Add LED support with double tap") and quit.
>
>    ```
>     debuild -us -uc -i -I
>     sudo dpkg -i ../xserver-xorg-input-synaptics_*.deb
>    ```
> 2. Build a dkms module for psmouse
>
>    ```
>     cd .. 
>     apt-get source linux-image-`uname -r`
>     sudo mkdir -p /usr/src/psmouse-`uname -r`/src
>     sudo cp linux-*/drivers/input/mouse/* /usr/src/psmouse-`uname -r`/src/
>     sudo gedit /usr/src/psmouse-`uname -r`/dkms.conf
>    ```
>
>    put this text, save the
>      file and exit gedit : (remplace *your kernel version* by the text
>      obtain with the command `uname -r`. For me, it's 2.6.38-9-generic)
>
>    ```
>     PACKAGE_NAME="psmouse" PACKAGE_VERSION="_your kernel version_"
>     CLEAN="rm -f *.*o"
>
>     BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="psmouse" MAKE[0]="make -C $kernel_source_dir
>     M=$dkms_tree/$PACKAGE_NAME/$PACKAGE_VERSION/build/src psmouse.ko"
>     BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="src" DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates"
>
>     AUTOINSTALL="yes"
>    ```
>
>    Close the file and:
>
>    ```
>     wget https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/582809/+attachment/3183441/+files/synaptics_led_support_v2-ubuntu_12.04.patch -P /tmp
>     cd /usr/src/psmouse-`uname -r`
>     sudo patch -p1 -i /tmp/synaptics_led_support_v2-ubuntu_12.04.patch >          sudo dkms add -m psmouse -v `uname -r`
>     sudo dkms build -m psmouse -v `uname -r` 
>     sudo dkms install -m psmouse -v `uname -r`
>    ```
>
>    3) Restart your computer and enjoy !

The patches are for 1.6 sources so you will have to modify them a bit to work with 1.8

Comment: Linux is a fast moving target, this solution will have a very short shelf life...

Comment: Why is this not in by default?